# Magento product page in IE8: add to cart increments by default value, ignoring quantity field. form.js line 266 errors

Tags: php, javascript, magento

The default form.js file appears to be erroring when "add to cart" is clicked. This prevents the value of the quantity field from correctly being passed. Magento substitutes the default value instead. This script doesn't error and the quantity field works just fine in other browsers.

Furthermore, the add to cart button works correctly when I switch back to the default theme. Any ideas on where I should start. does anything here stand out as not being IE8 friendly? I haven't modified any of the add to cart functions, nor the form.js file.

**Update:** I have a browserstack account. Debugging shows that VarienForm is undefined which throws two "'productAddToCartForm' is null or not an object" errors. Form.js which defines VarienForm is being loaded in the header so it should be available for the inline JS.

since you can't see line numbers here is the line in question:

```
this.regionSelectEl.options.add(option);
```

Here is the function:

```
update: function()
{
    if (this.regions[this.countryEl.value]) {
        var i, option, region, def;

        def = this.regionSelectEl.getAttribute('defaultValue');
        if (this.regionTextEl) {
            if (!def) {
                def = this.regionTextEl.value.toLowerCase();
            }
            this.regionTextEl.value = '';
        }

        this.regionSelectEl.options.length = 1;
        for (regionId in this.regions[this.countryEl.value]) {
            region = this.regions[this.countryEl.value][regionId];

            option = document.createElement('OPTION');
            option.value = regionId;
            option.text = region.name.stripTags();
            option.title = region.name;

            if (this.regionSelectEl.options.add) {
                this.regionSelectEl.options.add(option); //***this is line 266***
            } else {
                this.regionSelectEl.appendChild(option);
            }

            if (regionId==def || (region.name && region.name.toLowerCase()==def) ||
                (region.name && region.code.toLowerCase()==def)
            ) {
                this.regionSelectEl.value = regionId;
            }
        }

        if (this.disableAction=='hide') {
            if (this.regionTextEl) {
                this.regionTextEl.style.display = 'none';
            }

            this.regionSelectEl.style.display = '';
        } else if (this.disableAction=='disable') {
            if (this.regionTextEl) {
                this.regionTextEl.disabled = true;
            }
            this.regionSelectEl.disabled = false;
        }
        this.setMarkDisplay(this.regionSelectEl, true);
    } else {
        if (this.disableAction=='hide') {
            if (this.regionTextEl) {
                this.regionTextEl.style.display = '';
            }
            this.regionSelectEl.style.display = 'none';
            Validation.reset(this.regionSelectEl);
        } else if (this.disableAction=='disable') {
            if (this.regionTextEl) {
                this.regionTextEl.disabled = false;
            }
            this.regionSelectEl.disabled = true;
        } else if (this.disableAction=='nullify') {
            this.regionSelectEl.options.length = 1;
            this.regionSelectEl.value = '';
            this.regionSelectEl.selectedIndex = 0;
            this.lastCountryId = '';
        }
        this.setMarkDisplay(this.regionSelectEl, false);
    }
```

Comment: Check permissions. Maybe Form.js isn't readable.

Answer (score 0):

Region selection should only be triggered in cart or checkout. Check if your template uses own JS-Files in `skin/frontend/your_theme/js`. I think your template was made for a different Magento version so the CSS-Selectors in your phtml-files don't fit the JS anymore. So you have either to use Matching JS-Files or compare your product template to the one in base template and adapt CSS classes.

Comment: This would make a lot of sense. I've recently performed an update. Looking into this now. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: When I add to cart it redirects me to the cart. This is why region updater is being triggered. I commented out the region updater call to see if the error is preventing the quantity from being passed. Even without the error quantity does not pass.

Comment: Made any progress? Maybe you could provide a url to check your problem?